# How to accumulate a column based on a condition

Tags: powerquery, accumulate

I am trying to go through a list and mark parents so I can join an flat list onto it self

```
ID  Type     Idx 
200 EPIC      0
201 Feature   1
202 Feature   2
203 Feature   3
204 EPIC      4
205 Feature   5
206 Feature   6


Prefeered result
ID  Type     Idx   Parent   
200 EPIC      0    200     
201 Feature   1    200
202 Feature   2    200
203 Feature   3    200
204 EPIC      4    204
205 Feature   5    204
206 Feature   6    204
```

I have tried making self-referencing conditional columns but thats not possible,

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Parent", each if [Work Item Type] = "Epic" then [ID] else #"Added Custom"{[Index]-1}[ID]),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add custom column. Fill down.  Assuming data is in Table1 with 2 columns named ID and Type, then

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Parent", each if [Type]="EPIC" then [#"ID"] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Parent"})
in #"Filled Down"
```